# Non-negative Orthogonal Matching Pursuit

Tags: scikit-learn

For my research with stocks, I want to construct a synthetic stock (from a linear-combination of other stocks). I want to use OMP from sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.OrthogonalMatchingPursuit.html

The problem is that it outputs atoms with *negative* coefficients - which is an applicative problem, as that induces short-selling a stock (I don't want that for now). Is there other implementation for non-negative OMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/davebiagioni/pyomp seems to be an option for OMP with non-negative constraint. Not very actively maintained though.